# Loading datatable column header from json

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I know there are similar questions about this topic, but the few of them which have answers seem to be outdated.

How do I set the table header for the columns from a json-source? Generating the arrays and encoding them to json isn't a porblem, yet I don't know how to assign them to  tags.

My table is a standard datatable, loading its content from a json file:

```
$('#statistik').dataTable({
            "destroy": true,
            "sDom": '<"F"fp><""l>',
            "columnDefs": [{type: 'de_datetime', targets: [1]}],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "ajax": path
        });
```

Which looks like this, when I try to set the header:

```
{"aoColumns":[["Test","Test2", "Test3"]] "data":[["Name",1,1]}
```

Comment: You likely want to look at using `$.extend` to mrege your default options and remote options. When you say other answers seem outdated you should really explain why and reference what you tried using those answers that didn't work